# What I need to change or add in the code to create a concatenate as table with vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

Currently, I have this final table:
[image]

I have this code to concatenate all data in the same row.

```
sub concatenate()
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=CONCATENATE(RC[-7],"","",RC[-6],"","",RC[-5],"","",RC[-4],"","",RC[-3],"","",RC[-2])"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H9"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H2:H9").Select
Range("H1").Select
end sub()
```

However, the "YEAR", "MONTH" and "VALUE" don't apear like I want ( with same formate as table)
[image]

What I need to change or add in the code to create a concatenate as table?

The current result:
[image]

Comment: Use the `TEXT` formula to format those values.

Comment: Can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: How about the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)?

Comment: I tried this: 
=text(A2,"yyyy")&","&text(B2,"mm")&","&C2&","&D2&","&text(E2,0000000.00)&","&F2)
But didn't function...

Comment: If year by local region is "aaaa" then text needs to be "aaaa" instead of "yyyy" (I have found it for spanish language being used), where did it broke by using the text one that you stated above?

Comment: The problem is with value, because it doesn't assume the format 0000000.00

Comment: You need the quotation marks on that one too text(E2,"0000000.00")

Comment: I see that you edited the question and you have the results in the concatenate, I do not understand the problem now, do you want to append to the VBA code this excel formula? =text(A2,"yyyy")&","&text(B2,"mm")&","&C2&","&D2&","&text(E2,"0000000.00")&","&F2)

Comment: If it is possible, I would like! Still I don't know how I do to change 0000000,00 to 0000000.00 because if i change , to . the value change, for example: 0000003,14 -> I owuld like to change to 0000003.14 and not to 0000000.03